# Hibernate Illegal State Exception

Tags: java, hibernate, servlets

I am new in **Hibernate** and while using the **Hibernate**, I encounters *IllegaStateException* a couple of times, the exception is not consistent as I don't know on what particular condition it happens, sometimes it never happens but sometimes it happens, I am unable to figure out how can it be resolved, please shed some light on this.

```
May 14, 2013 5:32:40 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader loadClass
INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load com.mysql.jdbc.ProfilerEventHandlerFactory.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.

java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1600)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.realClose(ConnectionImpl.java:4412)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.close(ConnectionImpl.java:1564)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.stop(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.finalize(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:229)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer.invokeFinalizeMethod(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer.runFinalizer(Finalizer.java:101)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer.access$100(Finalizer.java:32)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run

(Finalizer.java:178)
```

This is very upsetting. Also I am using one of my created wrapper to work with Sessions and SessionFactory. 
Also I checked my code I used **closeSession()** every time I used in my **dao's** that are working with **Hibernate** api internally.

This is my **ManagerSessionFactory**(Wrapper)

```
public class ManagerSessionFactory {

private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
private static Configuration configuration;
protected static ThreadLocal<Session> threadLocal = new ThreadLocal<Session>();

static void initializeSessionFactory(String configFilePath) {
    try {
        // Create the SessionFactory from standard (hibernate.cfg.xml) 
        // config file.
        configuration = new Configuration();
        sessionFactory = configuration.configure(configFilePath).buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        // Log the exception. 
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex.getMessage());
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}

private static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}

public static Session createSession() {
    return createSession(null);
}

public static Session createSession(String configFilePath) {

    if (configFilePath == null || configFilePath.trim().equals("")) {
        configFilePath = "/hibernate.cfg.xml";
    }
    SessionFactory localSessionFactory = ManagerSessionFactory.getSessionFactory();
    Session session = ManagerSessionFactory.threadLocal.get();

    if (session == null || !session.isOpen()) {

        if (localSessionFactory == null) {
            try {
                ManagerSessionFactory.initializeSessionFactory(configFilePath);
                localSessionFactory = ManagerSessionFactory.getSessionFactory();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("%%%% Error Creating SessionFactory %%%% " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        session = localSessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        System.out.println("Session Opened......");
        ManagerSessionFactory.threadLocal.set(session);
    }



    return session;
}

public static void closeSession(){
    closeSession((Session)ManagerSessionFactory.threadLocal.get());
    return;
}

public static void closeSession(Session session){

    if (session != null && session.isOpen()) {
        session.close();
        //ManagerSessionFactory.threadLocal.
    }
    session = null;

    return;
}
}
```

And this is **ManageTransaction** that extends the functionalities of the previous class :

```
public class ManageTransaction extends ManagerSessionFactory {

private Session session;
private Transaction transaction;
private String configFilePath;
private boolean toStartTransaction;

public ManageTransaction() {

    this.session = ManagerSessionFactory.createSession();
    initManagerTransaction("", false, session);
}

public ManageTransaction(boolean toStartTransaction) {
    this.session = ManagerSessionFactory.createSession();
    if (toStartTransaction) {
        this.transaction = this.session.getTransaction();
        this.transaction = this.transaction.isActive() ? this.transaction : this.session.beginTransaction();
    }
    initManagerTransaction("", toStartTransaction, session);
}

public ManageTransaction(boolean toStartTransaction, String configFilePath) {

    if (toStartTransaction) {
        this.session = ManagerSessionFactory.createSession();
        this.transaction = this.transaction.isActive() ? this.transaction : this.session.beginTransaction();
    }
    initManagerTransaction(configFilePath, toStartTransaction, this.session);

}

public ManageTransaction(String configFilePath, boolean toStartTransaction) {

    ManagerSessionFactory.initializeSessionFactory(configFilePath);
    if (toStartTransaction) {
        this.session = ManagerSessionFactory.createSession();
        this.transaction = this.transaction.isActive() ? this.transaction : this.session.beginTransaction();
    }
    initManagerTransaction(configFilePath, toStartTransaction, this.session);
}

public ThreadLocal<Session> getThreadLocal() {
    return threadLocal;
}

private void initManagerTransaction(String configFilePath, boolean toStartTransaction, Session session) {
    this.configFilePath = configFilePath == null ? "" : configFilePath;
    this.toStartTransaction = toStartTransaction;
    ManageTransaction.threadLocal.set(session);
}
public void closeManageTransaction() {
        afterEveryOperation(true);
        ManagerSessionFactory.closeSession(this.getSession());
    }

}
```

This is my **hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/befundo?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <!--mapping classes -->
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is 10% complete how do you expect answer. 
Provide more details like your HibernateUtil etc.

Comment: Ok, I gave my Factory Class that is taking care of managing the transactions and session and just keeping the boilerplate code outside from the core logic...

Comment: Most possibly you have missing or mixing jars.

Comment: @erencan it is working, if jars were missing how can it work.

Comment: Do you have all the appropriate mysql jars on the classpath? Also it appears that your entire connection pool is being garbage collected periodically which is probably an even bigger problem. Thirdly does this problem coincide with hot deploying .wars into a running container?

Comment: 1.Mysql jars are there in the classpath, because I am not getting any **error** there.
2.My connection pool is garbage collected, I don't understand the comment
3.What is Hot Deploying wars in running container.
Please elaborate...
:(

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are not closing the SessonFactory.  The session factory is creating a connection pool.  This will be closed (connections released) when the sessionFactory is closed.  Since you are not explicitly closing it the close is being called when the object is garbage collected (finalize method).  This is after the webapp has been undeployed.

A quick fix would be to add a ServletContextListener and close the session factory in the destroy method.

Your code also looks very complicated and you will have a lot of issues with it.  It would be better to use something like spring or EJB sessions beans to handle this.

Comment: Thanks for such a great thought, I am learning spring and very soon change the boiler plate code to be start working with the **Spring**